Unable to configure NGINX to handle CORS
I am using Weblow in frontend (www.example.com) and a separate server to serve backend data via JSON (api.example.com).
I use Nginx and my configuration is as per below:
server {
 server_name api.example.com;
 index file.json;

location / {
    root /var/www/example/html;
    default_type application/json;
    add_header Content-Type application/json;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*";
 }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/l
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*";
    if ($host = api.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 listen 80;
 server_name api.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

My frontend code looks something like below:
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://api.example.com";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xmlhttp.send();

But my request has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
However, my request still kept blocked by CORS.
Would like to know what's wrong with my code above?
Thanks a lot in advance.
I have tried to add header allowing CORS in Nginx but not working.

please add the response to curl -I the-url to the question, or use browser tools and from the network tab put the copy-as-curl request and response in the question.

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"; this is in location / twice - there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header there. Looks like a simple typo :).

Thanks. But after i made correct access-control-allow-method, its still not working. Just wanna ask How do i add curl -I? Thanks a lot.

curl is a cli tool. The -I flag is used to emit a HEAD request and show only the response headers.

I get it solved. My configuration of Nginx looks like below:
location / {
add_header Content-Type application/json;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";
if ($request_method = OPTIONS){
    return 204;
}
root /var/www/example/html;
default_type application/json;

}

$request_method = OPTIONS is too restrictive. Not all OPTIONS requests should be categorised as CORS-preflight requests.

@jub0bs please indicate how to action your comment.

@AD7six A comment is too short; I could post an answer, but that's not the main focus of the OP's question. But I can link to this: https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly
